# Printing all properties in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I am following a code academy tutorial and i am finding this difficult.

The assignment is the following:

> Use a for-in loop to print out all the properties of nyc.

```
var nyc = {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

// write your for-in loop here
for (var  in nyc){
    console.log(population);
}
```

Comment: i could try typing all the properties i want, but i want to select all

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rJBf3/

Comment: If you have so much trouble with the Codeacademy assignments, then maybe you should follow another tutorial to get a better grasp of the basics. For example: http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html.

Answer (score 57):

Your syntax is incorrect. The `var` keyword in your `for` loop must be followed by a variable name, in this case its `propName`

```
var propValue;
for(var propName in nyc) {
    propValue = nyc[propName]

    console.log(propName,propValue);
}
```

I suggest you have a look here for some basics:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 10):

What about this:

```
var txt="";
var nyc = {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

for (var x in nyc){
    txt += nyc[x];
}
```