# How to list all component properties

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, properties

I want to list all the component properties (both private and public) in angular.

I have tried the following

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.constructor.prototype);
}
```

But this is printing only the properties that have `getter` methods defined. It is not printing the properties which do not have `getters` or `setters`. It also prints component `methods` which I am not bothered.

Strange part is, it is not even displaying the public properties (which do not have getters).

Even I tried doing

```
console.log(this.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty('_queryState'));
```

But it returns me `false`, which means it was not able to identify the property.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) does not help me though.

How do I list all the properties?

If anyone is asking me why do I need to do this, it is for unit testing.

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17627940/885626

Comment: @Ric That still prints the same result. No private properties were printed.

Comment: Are the properties initialized ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174696/get-class-interface-properties-in-angular-5-typescript-without-assigning-a-d/49174833#49174833

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir No, but I tried printing them after initializing the private property. It is still not present in the result

Comment: If the properties are initialized they will show up if you use `Object.keys`, they will not appear on the prototype because they are not there they are instance level fields

Comment: I initialized the private property and did `Object.keys(this.construtor.prototype)`. But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript `Object.keys` :

```js
let component = {a: 17, b: 'test', c: [17, 17, 17]};
let keys = Object.keys(component);

for(let key of keys) {
  console.log('component[' + key + '] = ' + component[key]);
}
```

[Here is a running stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50700607)

Comment: component is not a javascript object in my case. It is an angular component. And also `Object.keys(this.construtor.prototype)` does not print private properties even though they are initialized.

Comment: How do you declare your component ? The stackblitz example logs an angular component properties into console.

Comment: Sorry, I had got confused. The private properties don't show up if I don't initialize them first. I guess I really don't have a nice way to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174696/get-class-interface-properties-in-angular-5-typescript-without-assigning-a-d/49174833#49174833.